# Mining Monero with NvidiaGTX1080

Tags: mining-hardware

Is it profitable to mine Monero with GTX1080? 
And what would be the best hardware to mine it with?

B.R 
Jan

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the hashrates of various GPUs and CPUs on [monerobenchmarks.info](http://monerobenchmarks.info/) or [google docs monero gpu/cpu comparison](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E0GqJdLhMmeO5BW3RBcIpftMR_BJhnyUS464ZO_EYGQ/edit?pref=2&pli=1#gid=0).

The GTX 1080 should get around 590 H/s, which at the current difficulty should get you around 0.04 XMR per day.

Whether this is profitable or not depends on your electricity costs, at $0.12/kwH, you should expect the card to cost about $0.51 in power per day to run (not including the rest of the system).

You can use [the cryptocompare mining calculator](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/xmr) to check things out for yourself.

Have fun :)